# How to customize the Home Screen Widget in Android Automotive App

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-auto, android-automotive

How I can customize the Home Screen widget in Android Automotive OS.
I have tested apps on polestar and volvo, but I didn't find any solution to update or customize the home screen widget.

Widget Findings:

1. Tested with API and classes provided by Android framework i.e AppWidgetProvider Class, it didn't work.
2. Tested with getSystemAvailableFeatures() API provided by Android and in polestar Emulator "android.software.app_widgets" doesn't exist but "android.software.app_widgets" exists in Pixel Emulator. That means the AppWidget feature doesn't support Polestar devices.
3. Tested with Media Sample App, the Home screen widget updated without using the  AppWidgetProvider Class, As Internally MediaBrowserServiceCompat class handles the Home widget(We can customize the media widget like title, play pause button, etc).
4. As per the Official Document of the Android Developer page :
   Android Auto supports 3 main types of system widgets for helping users multitask:
   ~~ Dialer widgets for controlling ongoing phone calls
   ~~ Navigation widgets for showing turn-by-turn instructions when not in maps
   ~~ Media widgets for controlling ongoing media play while in other apps

Comment: No one have solution for this?